# Ajax post to php file CORS Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

[Network error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2q0M.png)I am trying to run an ajax post method to a php file called calendar.dec.php. I keep getting the error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

Here is my ajax post method

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'includes/calendar.dec.php',
          data: {ajax: 1,sunday: sunday},
          success: function(response){              
              let index = response.search("<!DOCTYPE");
              var div = document.createElement("div");
              div.innerHTML = response.slice(0, index);
              response = div.innerText;
              $('#test').text(response);
              console.log(response);
              let content = response.substring(1, response.length-1).split(",");
              for(let i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
                content[i] = content[i].replace(/"|'/g, '');
              }
              console.log(content);
              document.getElementById("sunday").innerHTML = content[0];
              document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML = content[1];
              document.getElementById("tuesday").innerHTML = content[2];
              document.getElementById("wednesday").innerHTML = content[3];
              document.getElementById("thursday").innerHTML = content[4];
              document.getElementById("friday").innerHTML = content[5];
              document.getElementById("saturday").innerHTML = content[6];
          }
      });
```

Here is the beginning code to the calendar.dec.php.

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  require 'dbh.inc.php';
  session_start();
  $uid = $_SESSION['userUid'];  
  if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){ 
    global $sunday;
    global $monday;
    global $tuesday;
    global $wednesday;
    global $thursday;
    global $friday;
    global $saturday;

    $sunday = $_POST['sunday'];
      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM week WHERE uid = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("Location: ../calendar.php?error=sqlerror"); //might need to change this to index
        exit();
    }
    else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $uid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $index = null;

          $s = explode("~ ", $row['sunday']);
          $m = explode("~ ", $row['monday']);
          $t = explode("~ ", $row['tuesday']);
          $w = explode("~ ", $row['wednesday']);
          $th = explode("~ ", $row['thursday']);
          $f = explode("~ ", $row['friday']);
          $sa = explode("~ ", $row['saturday']);

          
          for($x = 0; $x < count($s)-1; $x+=2){
            if($s[$x] == $sunday){
              $index = $x;
            }
          }
          
          
          global $s_content;
          global $m_content;
          global $t_content;
          global $w_content;
          global $th_content;
          global $f_content;
          global $sa_content;

          if(isset($index)){
            $s_date = $s[$index];
            $s_content = $s[$index+1];

            $m_date = $m[$index];
            $m_content = $m[$index+1];

            $t_date = $t[$index];
            $t_content = $t[$index+1];

            $w_date = $w[$index];
            $w_content = $w[$index+1];

            $th_date = $th[$index];
            $th_content = $th[$index+1];

            $f_date = $f[$index];
            $f_content = $f[$index+1];

            $sa_date = $sa[$index];
            $sa_content = $sa[$index+1];

            $week = array($s_content, $m_content, $t_content, $w_content, $th_content, $f_content, $sa_content);
            print_r(json_encode($week));
          }
          else{
            $week = array("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
            print_r(json_encode($week));
          }       
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      $sunday = " ";
    }
?>
```

I also attached an image of the network tab where you can see that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not being added.

I've tried adding

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
headers: {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Header': '*'
},
```

inside the post method. I've also tried adding
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`
to calendar.dec.php which worked in localhost but not online for some reason. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` etc should be set by the PHP script

Comment: "_is [not] present on the __requested resource___". Access-Control-Allow-* are resopnse headers, it's not useful to set those in a request.

Comment: I did find that adding those headers to the ajax request didn't do anything. I have the header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") in the php script so where else could the issue be?

Comment: Have you got the network image and `calendar`?

Comment: Please add the full php script. The php above does not have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a few edits.

Comment: It looks like your POST request got _redirected_ elsewhere, with a 302 status code, and the Location header pointing to `https://errors.infinityfree.net/errors/403/` - so you need to go and figure out why that happens in the first place.